# Missing Artifact Spring data cassandra 1.5.0M1

Tags: java, spring, maven, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I try to use spring data cassandra 1.5.0 but when i update my pom by adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <name>Spring Milestones</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

But i got error

```
Missing artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:1.5.0.M1
```

I have to use this version because of its support for cassandra 3.0.

The question is how could I use this version?

Comment: There is no `spring-data-cassandra-core`, just `spring-cql` and `spring-data-cassandra`.

Comment: I tried with your setup and it ran just fine.

Comment: I edited it. I read somwhere that this change can fix the problem but it wont work.

Comment: Have you checked that you can access the repository? If your are behind a proxy, the may not be the case.

Comment: I see that repo is working.
`Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra/1.5.0.M1/spring-data-cassandra-1.5.0.M1.pom`
`3K downloaded  (spring-data-cassandra-1.5.0.M1.pom)`
Have you checked following URL in browser:
https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra/1.5.0.M1/
?

Comment: @JF Meier was right. Proxy blocked repository